# Testing code which requires a domain account from a non-domain computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, active-directory, tdd, cross-domain, vpn

I'm writing code which connects to Active Directory to query and manipulate user accounts.  This code includes test sets.  I'm currently developing this solution on my home machine, but to test against AD I need to connect to the company's network over VPN.  My home machine is not on the company domain, but I need to run under a domain account in order for the AD queries to work.  Is there a simple way to do this, or is my only straight forward option to remote onto my company workstation and run the tests there, or have my personal machine added to the company's domain?

Answer (score 1):

I've no real experience with AD, though this is not an issue at all. In fact, this will help prove my point.

Lets say there is a method to return all users within a group, in the code I was developing if I was yourself, I would abstract this behind my own interface. For example:

```
public class UserGroupFinder : IGroupFinder
{
    public Users FindBy(Group group)
    {
        // Code to interact with AD here
        // Note, Users and Group would be my own classes, not AD.
    }
}
```

Then I would write the application in question against IGroupFinder, rather than a real, fully fledge AD system. This means I could write unit tests (or other automated tests) from home, your office or anywhere for that fact!

As long as your code "does the right thing" once it finds all users for a group you should be fine. For example, you could filter the results of this query for all users that have a surname beginning with "F". This is your domain logic, nothing to do with Active Directory. You will *test drive* this, **not** the code required to interact with a third party.

The last step would be to actually create the concrete instances of your domain objects. So once you have a system where AD is configured, you can actually begin to wire these implementations up. I would not unit test this, because by this very definition this is not a unit test. This code will simply be a call into third party code, which will be tested by Microsoft.

Comment: Hey Finglas, thanks for your response.  Unfortunately the code I want to test is the code that interacts directly with AD.  What you've provided is great for testing the rest of my code without AD, but I'm really after some kind of AD mock up which I can test queries against.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm unaware of anything that would act as a "fake" AD. Due to this I can only recommend the above approach with manual testing/integration testing of the concrete classes, though this would require a real AD setup as you mentioned. Good luck though.